# How to make read only checkbox with extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am newbie with extjs. I create the checkbox with extjs 4 like

```
            xtype       : 'checkbox',
            fieldName   : 'test_checkbox',
            id          : 'test_checkbox',
            name        : 'test_checkbox',
            inputValue  : 1,
            fieldLabel  : 'Test checkbox',
```

I want to make this checkbox is read only. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try to avoid using `id's`. You mostly don't need them and the framework can override them. `fieldName` is not a property of the `checkbox control`,  why is it there?

Answer (score 3):

Set the [`readOnly`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-readOnly) property declarative:

```
{
    xtype : 'checkbox',
    name        : 'test_checkbox',
    inputValue  : 1,
    fieldLabel  : 'Test checkbox',
    readOnly: true
}
```

Or at runtime:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkbox[name=test_checkbox]')[0].setReadOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabled property :

```
xtype : 'checkbox',
fieldName   : 'test_checkbox',
id          : 'test_checkbox',
name        : 'test_checkbox',
inputValue  : 1,
fieldLabel  : 'Test checkbox',
disabled: true
```

Comment: Readonly and disabled are two different things in standard html forms. Readonly fields will be posted, disabled fields not. That's the main difference.